# Firefox Scratchpad How to use library like jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scratchpad

I am using JavaScript, JQuery and [JSTree](https://www.jstree.com/) in a project. I would love to use [Firefox Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad) to incrementally develop this project. Unfortunately, Scratchpad does not sense jstree.js.

Please suggest me how to integrate other jquery libraries into Scratchpad. Or is there any alternative to Scratchpad which can do this.

Edit: I had two files, one index.html which has all the html code and I am importing jquery and jstree in this file. Another file index.js which has all js, jquery and jstree code.

Now I know the problem could be that it needs to be served from a Tomcat server and that is Scratchpad is giving me that error. I forgot to add that error to this question, here it is:

```
/*
Exception: SyntaxError: '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/actors/utils/webconsole-utils.js:670:0
*/
```

I added this to Tomcat and Firefox Scratchpad is firing all well.

Thanks for your advice.

thanks and regards

BB23850

Answer (score 0):

I think scratchpad is for testing/manipulating existing sites you are on an opened browser. This means the site itself needs to be served from your place that you control and add there the files/libraries you need.

If you want to build your own online, you can use [Mozilla Thimble](https://thimble.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/), [codepen](http://codepen.io/) and others.

Comment: thanks for your help. I found a answer and updated my question accordingly.